# In Politecnico di Milano, Does the university wait until the end of the deadline to review all the documents?

Tags: phd, application, italy

I am preparing for applying for a Ph.D. program at the Politecnico di Milano in Italy. I am working on the initial proposal. The 36th call starts on April 26, 2020, through May 29, 2020. I don't know whether the university waits until the deadline to receive all the application forms and then review the documents or they start to review as they receive applications and when they reach their capacity before the deadline, for instance, mid-May, and then they quit the review and ignore the other upcoming documents from the students?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in Italy all the applications, for *whatever position* (PhD student, postdoc, professor) and regardless of the university, are reviewed after the deadline.

No, none of the applications that arrive on time can be ignored.